# -bash: /usr/sbin/start-systemd-namespace: No such file or directory

Tags: 20.04

I am using ubuntu 20.04, as I start my ubuntu 20.04 on Windows, it shows the message as title:

-bash: /usr/sbin/start-systemd-namespace: No such file or directory

How do I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Are you running WSL?

Comment: Yes, for ubuntu 20.04